# how to share the user current location map through email in windows UWP applications

Tags: c#, xaml

I am developing UWP application in that I want to share the users current location map through selected email is there any possibility to share the map.

Answer (score 0):

You could share the screenshot by using RenderTargetBitmap (EDIT: not sure if it will work on a map)
Or you could share the latitude and longitude in plain text
Or you could create bing static image and share link
Tutorial for bing static image 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701724.aspx

P.S google has even better api
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/